# Where do I put the css properties in the bootstrap row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry if this sounds dumb. But Im using bootstrap and I want to make a row inside a container have a background color of black with the height of 100 pixels. My question is, do I do that at the row level like so?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" style="background:black;height:100px;"></div>
</div>
```

Or is the proper way to do this is inside the row in a new div? Again sorry if this is a dumb question. But the length of the row is different from the first example vs the second example so want to make sure I am doing this correctly.

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><div style="background:black;height:100px;"></div></div>

</div>
```

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do. Does the inner DIV have additional/custom styles defined? It might not stretch to the full width of the parent. It might be floated, taken out of normal layout flow... so, without knowing the context, it is really difficult to give you the right answer. You can play around with dev tools in the browser and set inline styles for the different elements, and see which one suits you best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to add a style tag. You will need to make another css style sheet and declare the styling for that class.

Let's say it's a rails app.

In the stylesheets directory make a new stylesheet, it should end with .css

From there you will

```
.col-md-12 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
}
```

However you should note that columns are defined in the bootstrap library so you will want to add some sort of other class declaration so you don't over-ride all col-md-12 div's

In your html

```
class="anything col-md-12"
```

and in your css

```
.anything {
   background-color: black;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind that col-* classes in bootstrap have their own margins and paddings. So, if you place a div inside col- classes, then they will have those padding and then the style will be applied to the div.